# Change domain of images that webpack generates for imported images

Tags: javascript, webpack

Although my dev server is running on `localhost:3000`, I have set up my host file to point `www.mysite.com` to localhost. In my JavaScript, I have code like:

```
import myImage from '../assets/my-image.jpg'

const MyCmp => <img src={myImage} />
```

Using Webpack's `file-loader`, it transforms that import into a URL to the hosted image. However, it uses the `localhost` path to that image, but I'd like it to use the `www.mysite.com` domain. I looked at both the [`publicPath` and `postTransformPublicPath`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#publicpath) options for `file-loader`, but those only appear to allow you to modify the part of the path that comes *after* the domain.

Comment: When I use `file-loader` the path to the assets is just the "path" segments. Yours include the full url in the bundle files?

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't like the notion of defining host-information statically in the build output. This is something that should be determined in runtime based on where you actually put your files.

If you are like me then there are two options here.
Both involve you calling a global method that you have defined on i.e. window / global scope.
The purpose of the global method is to resolve the root path (the domain, etc) in runtime.

**Define a global method**

So lets say you define a method on the global scope somewhere in your startup code like so:

```
(<any>window).getWebpackBundleRootPath = function (webpackLibraryId) {
   if (webpackLibraryId == null) return throw "OOOPS DO SOMETHING HERE!";

   // Preferably these variables should be loaded from a config-file of sorts.
   if(webpackLibraryId == "yourwebpacklibrary1") return "https://www.yoursite.com/";
   // If you have other libraries that are hosted somewhere else, put them here...

   return "...some default path for all other libraries...";
};
```

The next step is to configure webpack to call this global method when it tries to resolve the path.
As I mentioned there are two ways, one that manipulates the output of the webpack and one that is more integrated in webpacks configuration (although only for file-loader but I think it should suffice).

It's worth mentioning that you don't need a global method if you only have one bundle or if you host all your bundles in one place. Then it would be enough to use a global variable instead. It should be quite easy to modify the example below to accommodate this.

### First option: configure webpack file-loader to call your method when resolving path

This solution will not require something to be done post build. If this fits your need and covers all scenarios I would go for this option.

**Edit your webpack config file**

```
var path = require('path');

let config = {
    entry: {
        'index': path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
        filename: 'index-bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'https://localhost:3000/',
        library: 'yourwebpacklibrary1',
        ...
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            // Please note that this only defines the resolve behavior for ttf. If you want to resolve other files you need to configure the postTransformPublicPath for those too. This is a big caveat in my opinion and might be a reason for using second option.
            test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    outputPath: 'assets/fonts', // The folder where you store your fonts.
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    // This is where the magic happens. This lets you override the output of webpack file resolves.
                    postTransformPublicPath: function (p) {

                        // Because of the way webpack file-loader works the input from to this method will look something like this: __webpack_public_path__ + "/assets/fonts/yourfont.ttf"
                        // But we are not interested in using the __webpack_public_path__ variable so lets remove that.
                        p = p.replace('__webpack_public_path__ + ', '');

                        // Return a stringified call to our global method and append the relative path to the root path returned.
                        return `getWebpackBundleRootPath("${config.output.library}") + ${p}`;
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
    },
    ...
};

module.exports = config;
```

As you might have noticed in the comments in the webpack config file you need to specify the resolve behavior for each file-loader that you add (if someone knows a better way, please let me know). This is why I still use the second option.

### Second option: manipulate the output of the webpack in a postbuild step

**Example webpack.config.js file**

For completeness sake here is an example of a webpack.config.js file that contains the variables used in the postbuild script.

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'index': path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
        filename: 'index-bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'https://localhost:3000/',
        library: 'yourwebpacklibrary1',
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

**Create a postbuild.js file**

Create a file postbuild.js next to your package.json with the following content:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// We take the path to the webpack config file as input so that we can read settings from it.
const webpackConfigFile = process.argv[2];

// Read the webpack config file into memory.
const config = require(webpackConfigFile);

// The file to manipulate is the output javascript bundle that webpack produces.
const inputFile = config.output.path + config.output.filename;

// Load the file into memory.
let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(inputFile, 'utf8');

// Replace the default public path with the call to the method. Please note that if you specify a publicPath as '/' or something very common you might end up with a problem so make sure it is unique in the file to avoid other unrelated stuff being replaced as well.
fileContent = fileContent.replace('"' + config.output.publicPath + '"', 'getWebpackBundleRootPath("' + config.output.library + '")');

// Save the manipulated file back to disk.
fs.writeFileSync(inputFile, fileContent, 'utf8');
```

**Call the postbuild.js automatically on build**

Next step is to actually call the postbuild.js script after each build.
This can be done in a post*script* in package.json like so (in the script section in your package.json):

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "postbuild": "node postbuild.js ./webpack.config.js"
    }
}
```

From now on whenever you run the build script it will also run the postbuild script (from npm or yarn, etc).

You can of course also manually run the postbuild.js script manually after each build instead.

Answer (score 0):

> but those only appear to allow you to modify the part of the path that comes after the domain.

Not really, you can give it an URL that includes the domain.

In your case, assuming your images are under the `assets` directory, you will have something like this in your `webpack.config.js`

```
...
module: {
  rules: [
    ...
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          publicPath: 'https://www.example.com/assets',
          outputPath: 'assets'
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
...
```